# Why is sql plus not including all of the data from my column with spool

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus, oracle-xe

I am using SQLPLUS to spool data out to a file, but not all of the data is being returned? I am using the `dbms_metadata.get_ddl` function and it is only returning part of the table definition to the file....where I can see the full definition in the query output.

I was setting `linesize = 8000` in the spool set?

SQL:

```
Select dbms_metatdata.get_ddl('TABLE',at.table_name)
From all_tables at
Where at.owner = 'MYTEST';
```

Outputting:

```
CREATE TABLE "MYTEST"."TESTTABLE3"
(   "ID" NUMBER(10,0),
"DESCRIPTION" V

CREATE TABLE "MYTEST"."MYPARENT"
(   "PARENT_ID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENAB
```

Totally truncating the output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `set long 1000000000`

Comment: @scarpacci - If it's not enough, you can go to set long 2000000000. Refer here for doc: http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-sqlplus-set.html "Set the maximum width (in chars) for displaying and copying LONG values."